# Scanner delimter to only take new line outside of double quotes in java

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I have requirement to read from the scanner based on new line only if its out side the double quotes.

Input :
`"Content1 \r\n block" \r\n Contentn2 \r\n  New Content " \r\n Conetent3"`

Expected Output :

> "Content1 \r\n block"

> Content2

> New Content " \r\n Conetent3"

I have tried with

```
String content = "\"Content1 \r\n block\" \r\n Contentn2 \r\n New conenet \" \r\n Conetent 3\"";
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(content);
String regex = "[^\"\r\n]+(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"\r\n]+)*";
while(fileScanner.hasNext())
{
String rec = fileScanner.findWithinHorizon(regex,0);
Sysyetem.out.println(rec);
}
```

but it not working as expected above, checked other also but none of them working for this

`/(?<=^[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*)\r?\n/` this worked in Javascript to get only outside \r\n, but not working in java throwing error when tried to use as fileScanner.useDelimter()
 `Look-behind group does not have obvuios maximum length`

Please suggest

Comment: How about matching `*\"[^\"]+\" *|[^\r\n\"]+`? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jVuXR8/1) (First character of the expression is a space.)

Comment: After 2nd line then eah values getting split on " also that would be wrong is'n it, New conenet " \r\n Conetent 3" supposed to be in a single match

Comment: It may be possible to manage this, but honestly, this is too complex a task for Scanner.  I’d be reading characters one by one and doing the parsing myself.

Comment: I now see the regex I suggested splits the string in a way that differs from your expected result, but I've concluded that I don't understand the question, specifically the first line. Could you edit to make that line more precise?

Comment: There is a pattern for this, and I forget the name.  It's similar to an _[Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)_.

Comment: This is the same problem as handing commas within fields in CSV files. There are several questions about this topic. Try searching on this site for `[regex] csv comma is:q`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, i am able to get this from the below regex.

`\r\n(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)`.

With this as a delimter all \r\n except in double quotes are considered split.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use a regular expression that matches
double-quoted strings or your `\r\n`, in two different named
capturing groups. This can be done with the use of `(?: | )` to do
an "**or**" condition (without capturing it) and then with
`(?<group_name> )` to create the named capturing groups.

To match a double-quoted string, it can be something like this:
`"(?:\\.|[^"])*"`

Explained:

- `"` matches the opening double-quote.
- `\\.` matches a backslash followed by any char. This is
  because **double-quotes are allowed in a string** and are usually
  escaped with a backslash. This way, we don't stop on a double
  quote. It will also handle this case properly:

  ```
  Input : "Backslash = \\" or "Tab = \t"
  ```

  If we just have `\\"` as pattern, then we would not match
  correctly the `"Backslash = \\"` string and continue until
  the next opening double-quote.

  This is where we see that using a regex with lookarounds
  isn't really a solution. We need to "consume" content like
  a parser would do. By the way, your content looks like some
  CSV content without the usual `,` or `;` delimiter. A CSV
  parser will handle strings properly. We have to try and do
  the same with our regex pattern ;-)

  **You have to check how double-quotes are escaped in
  your input**. For example, CSV syntax just doubles the
  quotes like this:

  ```
  1997,Ford,E350,"Super ""luxurious"" truck"
  ```
- `[^"]` will match any char which is not a double-quote.
- `(?: | )` is a non-capturing group with two possibilities.
  Adding the `*` behind means that it can be repeated 0 or N times.

The full regex, with the ***x*** flag for the *e**x**tended syntax*
will let you add comments and spaces in your regex, for better
reading.

The PCRE syntax (PHP), with the ***g*** flag for
***g**lobal/multiple*:

```
/
(?:
  # String with possible escaped char inside.
  (?<string>"(?:\\.|[^"])*")
| # or
  # \r\n, but outside a string (as it's tested after the string).
  (?<newline>\\r\\n)
)
/gx
```

**Test it on regex101 for *Java***: https://regex101.com/r/c0LZD2/3

You'll have to loop over the matches and test if the group named
*newline* (or the group of index 2) is filled or not. If it's filled
then replace it by your real newline.

I'm not a *Java* developer. I use *PHP* or *JavaScript* and do that
with a replacement callback, like this:

```js
// Same regular expression, but here without named capturing groups.
//
//                   g1 = string     g2 = newline & spaces
//                /¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯\ /¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯\
const regex = /(?:("(?:\\.|[^"])*")|(\s*\\r\\n\s*))/g;

const input = `Input : "Content1 \\r\\n block" \\r\\n Contentn2 \\r\\n New conenet " \\r\\n Conetent 3"
Input : "A string can contain \\"quotes\\"" \\r\\n Something else "\\" \\r\\n"
Input : "Tab = \\t | bell = \\a (\\"alert\\") | backslash = \\\\" \\r\\n "String 2" UnquotedString`;

console.log("input:");
console.log(input);
console.log("output:");
console.log(
  // Replace input:    callback   match      group 1     group 2
  //                       |        |           |           |
  input.replace(regex, function(fullMatch, quotedString, newLine) {
    // If the newLine group isn't empty, then replace it
    // by a real new line.
    if (newLine) {
      return "\n";
    // If not, don't change anything, so return the full match.
    } else {
      return fullMatch;
    }
  })
);
```

### Edit

Since the question was edited to be a bit clearer, **my answer isn't
valid any more**. The original question wasn't saying that `\r\n` was
already in *Java* strings, so I was literally looking for this
sequence of 4 characters and not the real carriage return and new
line characters.

It wasn't also clear that we had to stick using the `Scanner` class
and use a "split" kind of pattern.

Never mind... But in any case, don't forget to handle quotes in
strings as they aren't any details or assumptions about this point.

Comment: this is also not working, as the expections is with regex only need to be able to split direvtly, instead of wring a code on top of that

Comment: @SivaRam I don't think you will manage to do that with a regex to just split into lines with `\n\r` not inside a string. Usually, people would tell you tu use a proper parser, such as CSV. In this case, without the traditional `;` or `,` delimiters. I also don't think that using regex lookarounds will solve the problem either, because as *Java* told you, the lookbehind should have a fixed length. And this will not solve the case of a double quote character inside a double-quoted string. Need a bullet-proof solution? then go for a few lines of code with a callback and a bit of logic.

Answer (score 0):

Traverse *s*, appending a *substring* for any *line-feed*, when *b* is *false*.

```java
String s = "\"Content1 \r\n block\" \r\n Contentn2 \r\n  New Content \" \r\n Conetent3\"";
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
char[] a = s.toCharArray();
boolean b = false;
int t = 0;
for (int i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++)
    switch (a[i]) {
        case '"' -> b = !b;
        case '\n' -> {
            if (!b) l.add(s.substring(t, (t = i) + 1).trim());
        }
    }
l.add(s.substring(t).trim());
```

Here is the output, with `\r` and `\n` replaced with literals, for readability.

```
"Content1 \r\n block"
Contentn2
New Content " \r\n Conetent3"
```

---

Edit

If you expect *escaped* *quotation-marks*, `\"`, provide a  check, before flipping *b*.

```java
case '"' -> {
    if (i == 0 || a[i - 1] != '\\') b = !b;
}
```

Comment: This will not work if the string itself contains some quotes: `"Something can be \"quoted\" in the string"` (escaped by a backslash). I also think that the author of the question was obliged to use the `Scanner` class, and this is why my answer isn't solving his expectations either.

Comment: @PatrickJanser, a valid argument; I'll add it in.